# Check for repeated characters adjacent to each other in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the user to input a string like this starts and ends with (a), and there are repeated letters in between like this:

*"abbabbabbabbabba"*
the repetition can be: (bb), (bbb), (bbbbb) or more like this:
*"abbbabbbabbba"* or *"abbbbabbbbabbbba"*

I managed to check the start and end of the string like this:

```
input_sentence = input()
    if input_sentence[0] == 'a' and input_sentence[len(input_sentence) - 1] == 'a' :
        print('yes')
```

I tried to check the previous values like this:

```
pass= 'abbabbabba'
prev = ''
for character in pass:
    if character == prev:
       print("repeated character:", character)
    prev = character
```

Iut i just can check the repeated letters for one time.

Maybe it is not the right though, but I want to know how to check that a letter in repeated in a specific sequence in a string

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. The only thing I can suggest for now is that `input_sentence[len(input_sentence) - 1]` can be simply `input_sentence[-1]`. You also can't call your variables `pass` so this should be throwing errors.

Comment: Thank you.
I mean, how can i check that a letter is repeated in a specific manner like this:

(abbabbabba) how to check that bb is repeated through the whole string

Comment: If it is just a and b, I would split on a, and then look at the lengths of the strings of bs.

Comment: Do you need to check repetition of a's too?

Comment: I want like this:
Now the user input (abbabbabba)
Now i know that this string starts with 'a' and ends with 'a'

I want to check that after each 'a' there will be b's then 'a' appears again, then the same number of b's appper again then a, the same number of b's and end with a

something like this: 'abbbabbbabbba'

Comment: first of all; don't use that pass keyword; and secondly; your question is still unclear

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to check that the input matches the desired pattern.

```
>>> p = r'^(abb+)+a$'
>>> re.match(p, "abbabbabbabbabba")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 16), match='abbabbabbabbabba'>
>>> re.match(p, "abbbabbbabbba")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 13), match='abbbabbbabbba'>
>>> re.match(p, "abbbabbbaba")
>>>
```

The pattern `p` matches a string that consists entirely of one or more strings of "a" followed by at least two "b"s, with an "a" at the very end.

The `match` function will return a match object if the string matches the pattern, otherwise it will return `None`.

Comment: Thank you but just to clarify

for example i write like this:

import re
input_sentence = input()
p = r'^(abb+)+a$'
re.match(p, input_sentence)

Comment: @alfredjacob - that looks right, but you need to check the return value from the match function to see whether the string matches the pattern.

Comment: @alfredjacob your inputs look very like those used when working with automata in Computer Science courses.  If you're doing a CS course then your professors may prefer that you work out the algorithm from first principles rather than using a regex.  But it's worth knowing that automata and regexes are closely related concepts.  If you're not doing CS course, sorry for the gibberish comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

@f.wue

so should it be like this:

```
input_sentence = input-sequence.split("a")
if input_sentence.startswith('a') and input_sentence.endswith('a'):
    print('yes')

ex = 'abbabbabbabba'

def check_recursive(character, last_characters):
    sequence = character
    for i in reversed(range(0,len(last_characters))):
        if last_characters[i] == character:
            sequence += last_characters[i]
        else:
        return sequence

outputs = []
for i in reversed(range(1, len(ex))):
    output = check_recursive(ex[i], ex[:i])
    if output != ex[i]:
        outputs.append(output)
if len(set(outputs)) == 1:
    print("Only one type of sequence.")
```

Comment: @f.wue
Is this what you mean?

Comment: I will not edit my post with regard to your question. If your input will always be have an a, see https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp for some tutorial on how to use split. 
Please also take the tour to see how stackoverflow works: https://stackoverflow.com/tour
The goal is not to debug each line of your code, instead answer a specific question where you tried multiple things.